# How to select between brackets (or quotes or ...) in Vim?

Tags: vim, quotes, brackets, parentheses, yank

I'm sure there used to be a plugin for this kinda stuff, but now that I need it, I can't seem to find it (naturally), so I'll just ask nice and simple.

What is the easiest way to select between brackets, or quotes, or generally a list of matching characters?

```
   write ( *, '(a)' ) 'Computed solution coefficients:'
```

For example, here I'd like to select `(a)`, or `Computed solution coefficients:`.

I'm not interested in multiline, just cases which occur on one line.

Answer (score 315, accepted):

Use whatever navigation key you want to get inside the parentheses, then you can use either `yi(` or `yi)` to copy everything within the matching parens.  This also works with square brackets (e.g. `yi]`) and curly braces.  In addition to `y`, you can also delete or change text (e.g. `ci)`, `di]`).

I tried this with double and single-quotes and it appears to work there as well.  For your data, I do:

```
write (*, '(a)') 'Computed solution coefficients:'
```

Move cursor to the `C`, then type `yi'`.  Move the cursor to a blank line, hit `p`, and get

```
Computed solution coefficients:
```

As [CMS noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061933/how-to-select-between-brackets-or-quotes-or-in-vim/1062001#1062001), this works for visual mode selection as well - just use `vi)`, `vi}`, `vi'`, etc.

Comment: I'm generally looking for a way to select everything between predefined matching chars (normally only single and double quotes, and brackets of all kinds).

Comment: What do you mean by separated words?  I tried it on "[x, y, z]" and it picked out "x, y, z"

Comment: Disregard the last comment - found what the problem was. Works like a charm :-)

Comment: it seems to work with quotes as well `yi"` select all withing quotes

Comment: `ci(` or `ci)` does it for what I was looking for. Thanks. I still don't fully understand the `i` in that case, but who cares as long as it works, right ? :)

Comment: As noted below, check the help for text-objects.  the `i` is modifying the `c` command, so it's no longer "insert": I think of it as "inside" so `ci(` becomes "change inside parentheses".  If you want to include the parens, use `a` instead of `i` like `ca(`

Comment: I've added an answer below describing my plugin `vim-textobj-quotes` that provides a unified text object for handling different type of quotes with a single key binding.

Comment: is there any method that after yanking it goes to the insert mode?

Comment: Note that it is not needed to be inside the quotes when you call it, the own command looks for the first occurence of text inside quotes in the current line and deletes it, so you can save some key strokes.

Comment: Neat!  That's awesome - however, note that it only works with quotes.  Trying it with the parentheses didn't seem to work.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work very well with azerty (iso-fr) layout, because {, [, has to be accessed using the "Alt Gr" key.

Answer (score 416):

To select between the single quotes I usually do a `vi'`   ("select inner single quotes").

Inside a parenthesis block, I use `vib`   ("select inner block")

Inside a curly braces block you can use `viB` ("capital B")

To make the selections "inclusive" (select also the quotes, parenthesis or braces) you can use `a` instead of `i`.

You can read more about the [Text object selections](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#object-select) on the manual, or `:help text-objects` within vim.

Comment: thanks for that tip, I have been searching and asking for something similar and wasn't satisfied with my results. Awesome.

Comment: this tip is very simple and easy to commit inside my brain and muscle memory. thanks.

Comment: This is a highly useful tip. No more fumbling with extra keystrokes. Thank you for the link.

Comment: `vi"` to select inside double quotes "

Answer (score 33):

This method of selection is built-in and well covered in the Vim help. It covers XML tags and more.

See `:help text-objects`.

Comment: :help text-objects gets closer to the useful stuff... you could at least mention some of the common ones, like a" and a( when in visual mode.

Comment: (Also, +1 because despite being a long-time vim user, I didn't know about these!)

Comment: @Stobor . Cheers fixed that reference

Answer (score 29):

For selecting within single quotes use `vi'`.

For selecting within parenthesis use `vi(`.

Comment: Note: `ci'` or `ci(` for changing instead of visually selecting. But it does exactly what I wanted. Thanks :)

Comment: The second one only works when within that () block, so usually I do `%vi(` or `%vib`

Answer (score 11):

Use arrows or `hjkl` to get to one of the bracketing expressions, then `v` to select visual (i.e. selecting) mode, then `%` to jump to the other bracket.

Comment: (doesn't do quotes, unfortunately, though...)

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to add to the already good answers. I came here looking for a way to change the text inside of html brackets, so I want to provide an answer for anyone else that is also looking for that.

You might think `ci<` would work, but actually that only works if you are inside one of the tags themselves:

```
<would work inside here> But not here </would work inside here>
```

What I wanted was to change the text between the html tags themselves:

```
<div>change me</div>
```

What I wanted was "change inner tag": `cit`

Thank you to the other answer that mentioned the documentation (`:help text-objects`) which is how I found what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Stop at the beginning of brackets, and then select all and print:

```
vi' 

vi(

vi[ 

vi{

vi<

vi"
```

if you want to delete replace `vi` with `di`

Answer (score 3):

Write a Vim function in .vimrc using the `searchpair` built-in function:

```
searchpair({start}, {middle}, {end} [, {flags} [, {skip}
            [, {stopline} [, {timeout}]]]])
    Search for the match of a nested start-end pair.  This can be
    used to find the "endif" that matches an "if", while other
    if/endif pairs in between are ignored.
    [...]
```

(http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html)

Answer (score 3):

I would add a detail to the most voted answer:

If you're using gvim and want to copy to the clipboard, use

`"+<command>`

To copy all the content between brackets (or parens or curly brackets)

For example: `"+yi}` will copy to the clipboard all the content between the curly brackets your cursor is.

Comment: This is completely orthogonal to the problem and should not be an answer. You can write this on _every_ question which asks about `y`.

Comment: This is an addition to the answer, not an answer itself.

Comment: Then it should be an edit to that answer, this post as-is does not answer the question.

Comment: This is an advertisement for NOT using gvim :) Who needs an extra two shift+keypresses in their life?

Answer (score 1):

I've made a plugin `vim-textobj-quotes`: https://github.com/beloglazov/vim-textobj-quotes

It provides text objects for the closest pairs of quotes of any type. Using only `iq` or `aq` it allows you to operate on the content of single ('), double ("), or back (`) quotes that currently surround the cursor, are in front of the cursor, or behind (in that order of preference). In other words, it jumps forward or backwards when needed to reach the quotes.

It's easier to understand by looking at examples (the cursor is shown with `|`):

1. Before: `foo '1, |2, 3' bar`; after pressing `diq`: `foo '|' bar`
2. Before: `foo| '1, 2, 3' bar`; after pressing `diq`: `foo '|' bar`
3. Before: `foo '1, 2, 3' |bar`; after pressing `diq`: `foo '|' bar`
4. Before: `foo '1, |2, 3' bar`; after pressing `daq`: `foo | bar`
5. Before: `foo| '1, 2, 3' bar`; after pressing `daq`: `foo | bar`
6. Before: `foo '1, 2, 3' |bar`; after pressing `daq`: `foo | bar`

The examples above are given for single quotes, the plugin works exactly the same way for double (") and back (`) quotes.

You can also use any other operators: `ciq`, `diq`, `yiq`, `viq`, etc.

Please have a look at the github page linked above for more details.

Answer (score -8):

A simple keymap in vim would solve this issue.
    map viq F”lvf”hh
This above command maps viq to the keys to search between quotes. Replace " with any character and create your keymaps.
Stick this in vimrc during startup and you should be able to use it everytime.