# In Vim, how do I delete everything within the double quotes?

Tags: vim

Assuming I'm inside the quotes already.

Comment: This is closely related to [How to select between brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1061933/97073).

Answer (score 310, accepted):

Try the following sequence, which can be thought of as "d"elete, "i"nside, quotes, so:
<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>

Comment: Also see `:help text-objects` for other things that work similar to `"` in this situation.

Comment: @funk-shun:  See if `da"` does what you want.  The mnemonic would be "delete a quote[block]".  It deletes from quote to quote plus, I believe, any whitespace after the closing quote.

Comment: For me it's `di"<spacebar>`. For some keyboards it is necessary to hit spacebar to send the double quote character.

Comment: @funk-shun If you're trying to delete the quotes while leaving the text inside, check out [Vim-Surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround).

Comment: Strange bug(?) for me: this didn't work if the text-wrap was 'on' and the contents between the quotes flowed over two lines. I had to resize the window so it was all on one line. Then it worked fine.

Comment: Quite simple. Just replaced di' for single quotes.

Comment: For me it shows the message "--- Registers ---" and then asks to press ENTER, but it doesn't work at all. My line is like this `"foo": "bar",`

Comment: I always tried using this command without success; reason was that I was prepending `:` but you actually don't need to do this, go ahead and type `di"` immediately and it will work beautifully =D

Answer (score 34):

The following sentence drops everything inside the quotes while being in normal mode:

```
di"
```

where:

- d is for delete
- i is for "inner", just inside the following marker.
- " is for specifying that you will delete inside the quotes.

Note that **it is not needed to be inside the quotes when you call it, the own command looks for the first occurence of text inside quotes in the current line and deletes it, so you can save some key strokes.**

Additionally, if you are interested in deleting the quotes too, then apply the following command (a means "and around it")

```
da"
```