# Replace to end of text-object

Tags: vim

In Vim, I keep finding myself desiring a keystroke to rewrite the rest of some parameter list.  For example, in the following Python function:

```
def myfun(a, b=12, c=(1,2,3), d=15):
    pass
```

I wish to replace the `c=(1,2,3), d=15` with `e=12`.  The keystroke `ci(` allows me to replace everything inside the entire parameter list, but I find that I often want to retain some prefix of the Vim text-object.  In general, I'd assume this keystroke I'm searching for would be useful in the context of replacing final parameters of function calls as well as definitions.

A desirable answer to this question would apply to quoted strings, `[]` blocks and other text objects too.  Note that I understand all about text-objects as answered in "[How to select between brackets (or quotes or ...) in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061933/how-to-select-between-brackets-or-quotes-or-in-vim)".

Both @pb2q and @romainl give good search shortcuts, but they require me to visually find the end of the enclosing block to devise a search which is unambiguous in terms of any other garbage which is in the block  (e.g. think nested function calls).  In particular, I often find myself wanting this when I have nested parenthesis inside the parenthesis set I want to manipulate.  The answer I really want is analogous to `ci)` or `ca)` which is entirely conceptually based on the nearest enclosing bracketing `)` and deals entirely gracefully with other nested `)` blocks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a bunch of commands starting with <kbd>]</kbd> that go to the end of some kind of structure, and respect nesting. <kbd>]</kbd><kbd>)</kbd> to go to the end of a parenthesized block, <kbd>]</kbd><kbd>}</kbd> to go to the end of a braced block, <kbd>]</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> to go to the end of a C comment (`/*...*/` style). Use <kbd>[</kbd> in place of <kbd>]</kbd> to go to the beginning instead of the end.

So to do the replacement of your `c=(1,2,3), d=15` type <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>)</kbd>.

The complete list of these commands is listed under `:help various-motions`. Unfortunately there isn't one for blocks delimited by brackets, because <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> already had a different meaning in classical vi, and vim has defined <kbd>]</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> to fit nicely with those.

Comment: I believe this is the answer I'm looking for as far as native vim goes.  It's not as complete as I wish, but I suspect it's about as good as it gets with current vim.  I've wanted this in terms of replace to closing `)` (this answer achieves elegantly) and replace to closing `"` (this answer does not appear to achieve).

Comment: Since quotes aren't nestable, you can just use `/` to search for the next one. If this is the first you've heard of it, it may be a little surprising, but `/` is a motion command, therefore valid as an argument to the `c` command. Just type `c/"` and hit Enter.

Comment: Actually they're sort of nestable with `\"` aren't they? I guess I don't have a good answer for that. Submit a wishlist bug to vim for a `["` and `]"` command and maybe it'll appear in the next version

Comment: I like this answer best because the key sequence is shorter. But note the technique I suggested can easily be updated to work with `]`.

Comment: @darcyparker yes yours is nice too. And you taught me about the visual-mode `o` command which I didn't know before but I'll probably use soon.

Answer (score 5):

Create a map with this

```
mavi)o`a
```

- Mark the current position a
- visually select inside () to select the full set of characters inside the () that you are in
- go to the other end of the highlighted text `:h v_o` for more info
- move to the previously marked position

Now you can perform an operation such as c or d...

Edit: I still like @Alan-Curry's solution best because the key sequence is short. However this technique has the benefit of also working with ].

I also discovered a simplification for my solution:

```
vi)o``
```

`` jumps to the last position. So you don't need to create a mark.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a plugin, I believe [vim-ninja-feet](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-ninja-feet) does exactly what you are looking for.

- `c]i)` will change the rest of the parameter list,
- `d[i"` will
  delete backwards to the beginning of a quote, and
- `z]i]` will put you in insert mode at the end of a [] block.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ct:</kbd> in this case will change everything up to, but excluding, the `:`. Preceding the `t` with a numeric argument will allow you to comfortably change nested braces/parens/quotes, e.g. <kbd>c2t)</kbd>.

If the cursor is already on the line that you want to change, <kbd>fc</kbd> will put you on the character where you want to begin your change with the commands above, or use a search, e.g.: <kbd>/c=</kbd> for the more general case, i.e. if you have `c` characters earlier on the line, or the cursor is currently on a preceding line.

Comment: Yes, both true and both useful, but I'm going to have to say I'm pretty picky about the details.  For example, I might have a function call "... f(a, b, g(c, d)) ..." and wish to replace "b, g(c, d)" with "e" to get the result "... f(a, e) ...".

Comment: @jbmohler, you should be fine with `fb` then `cf)e`. Use `fc` followed by `cf5e=12` or `c2t)e=12` for the example in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I hacked together a small solution.  It may have some edge cases and may have some off-by-one errors but I don't have anymore time to test today.  I'll revisit when I have some time.

```
function! UntilTextObject(op)
    " Save marks
    let save_a = getpos("'a")
    let save_b = getpos("'b")

    " Read in the object type and set '< and '> to the ends of the
    " range of the text-object and 'a to the current position
    let object_type = nr2char(getchar())
    execute "normal! mavi" . object_type . "\<esc>"

    " Adjust end position (off by one)
    let pos = getpos("'>")
    let pos[2] += 1
    call setpos("'b", pos)

    " Operate on the range `a to `b
    execute "normal! `a" . a:op . "`b"

    " Restore marks
    call setpos("'a", save_a)
    call setpos("'b", save_b)
endfunction

onoremap u :call UntilTextObject(v:operator)<cr>
```

This allows you to do `du)` to delete-until-the-end-of-the-)-text-object.  Works for other text-objects as well.

I added a few changes that make this a little more polite by not stomping on your marks. It's still a little quirky if you give it a text-object that doesn't select anything.  I'll revisit this at a later date and see if I can figure that out.  It's intentionally over-commented for demonstration purposes.