# Copy text surrounded by curly braces

Tags: vim

I'm trying to copy the text inside curly braces and I need to copy the text plus the curly braces into register 'b'. There is a Vim command that could do this?

Comment: `:help text-objests`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select between brackets (or quotes or ...) in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061933/how-to-select-between-brackets-or-quotes-or-in-vim)

Answer (score 5):

Try it visually first:

```
va{"by
```

But you can go faster by doing it non-visually:

```
"bya{
```

Comment: Detailed explanation:

`v : enter visual mode`

`a{ : select content and curly braces itself`

`"by : yank into register b`